# Add double lines in the middle of another svg line

Tags: svg

so I have a drawing program and I need to implement a "broken line", it is an SVG line with two another lines in the middle of this line, these two line needs to cross perpendicularly to the principal line, maybe this picture can help me to explain the problem:

This line can be drawn in any angle that the user choose

[image]

I don't really understand svg's so I'm having a lot of trouble implementing this.

Thank you

Comment: If you don't understand SVG, then just telling what to copy-paste won't help you understand SVGs. Learn SVG: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered one way to implement that using polylines and calculating the middle of the source and target coordinates, so when it changes I change the middle point too. After that, I created a marker-mid with the double lines.